# Disabling Stats Collection from local.oplog.rs in MongoDB Ops Manager 5.0.x

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I am currently using MongoDB Ops Manager version 5.0.x for monitoring and managing my MongoDB deployments. I noticed that Ops Manager collects a significant amount of data from *local.oplog.rs*, which is causing some load on my system.

I am interested in configuring Ops Manager to stop or minimize the collection of these statistics from local.oplog.rs. I understand that this data is important for replication and sharding health monitoring, but due to the specific requirements and configurations of my deployment, I would like to reduce this load.

I’ve checked the official documentation and the Ops Manager interface, but I couldn’t find a direct setting or configuration option for this. I know that there are general settings for modifying data collection frequency and retention, but I am specifically interested in local.oplog.rs.

Could anyone guide me on how to disable or minimize stats collection from local.oplog.rs in MongoDB Ops Manager 5.0.x? Or if there are alternative ways to reduce the load caused by monitoring on my MongoDB instances, I would love to hear those too.

Thank you for your help!

I have read MongoDB Ops Manager Configuration document at: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ops-manager/v5.0/reference/configuration/ but I didn't find anything helpful.